# Parse "ld: framework not found Parse"

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6, ios-frameworks

I am trying to integrate Parse into my project. I copied the Parse.framework, Bolts.framework into my project, and made sure that the frameworks are being linked to in Build Phases. But I am getting the error "Framework not found Parse", with:

"ld: framework not found Parse
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Answer (score 0):

```
After add your parse framework  to your project
Click the + button in the bottom left of the 'Link Binary With Libraries' section and add the following libraries:

AudioToolbox.framework
CFNetwork.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
libz.dylib
libsqlite3.dylib
If you're using the -ObjC linker flag required by some third-party libraries, add these as well:

Accounts.framework
Social.framework

Are kindly check the following link to https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing
```

Comment: Kindly check  the following link  https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing